# Why does Grid doesnt accept expander.Content?

Tags: c#, wpf

In my method I have

```
public void method1(string table, Expander expander)
{
  Grid grid = expander.Content as Grid;
}
```

which doesn't works. Grid is still null.

I have another method where i use the same code and there it works.
I made a screen of debugging (expander.Content is not null).

I asked a friend who also don't know why it's not working.
[image: debugging]

Here a screen where u can see both methods (the second one with Grid is working fine)
[image]

Can someone explain me, why it doesn't work?

Comment: `expander.Content as Grid;` will be `null` if `expander.Content` is `null` or not of type `Grid`. So you may want to check if one of the two is the case.

Comment: yea but expander.Content is not null as you can see in the debugging screen.
The expander from the second method is also not a grid but still works.

Comment: your expander.Content is StackPanel here, not Grid..

Comment: @sTrenat but in the second method, the expander.Content is StackPanel aswell and there it works.

Comment: I now tried `StackPanel grid = expander.Content as StackPanel;`
which is not working too

Comment: And of what type was expander.Content this time?

Comment: null. but i guess i failed with debugging. i restart debugging and now StackPanel works. thanks for your answer i didn't thought this way.. god damn

Comment: You can always use some inheried type like `as Panel`

Comment: Some things that are discouraged here: Screenshots of code, screenshots of error messages, untranslated foreign-language content.

Answer (score 0):

> Can someone explain me, why it doesn't work?

Most likely because the `Content` property of the `Expander` has not been set to an instance of a `Grid`. The casting will only work if the `Content` property actually returns a `Grid`. You cannot cast something else than a `Grid` to a `Grid`.

If you use different kind of panels and simply want to be able to access the child elements, you could cast to a `Panel` instead:

```
public void method1(string table, Expander expander)
{
    Panel panel = expander.Content as Panel;
}
```